# How to apply native animation of objective c to react native views?

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native

I have tried applying native animation effect of objective c library to react native views but could not do that any help is appreciated

Comment: see this      https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-components-ios.html

Comment: i want to use react native view which has rendered from native method of objective c to apply animation from the third party library.and not to use native ui from react native. if you know how to access the react native view from native objective c method please share it

Comment: You set up the view model for RN in your xcode project, you can do anything you want with it.

Comment: Thanks @MotiAzu have successfully integrated native animation library with react native views but now subviews inside views not responding like button click of react -native views